# Why does Windows task manager show memory increases while writing very large files? Should I be worried?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, fwrite, large-files

I am developing a c++ application (in VS2012, Windows Server 2012 R2) that writes large volumes of binary data, from cyclical arrays of buffers that have been allocated, to raw files. The thing is that system RAM usage as reported by Windows Task Manager increases in a linear rate as fwrite writes the data in the files until it reaches a certain point where it remains almost constant (also see the following image). Also, the memory used by my application remains constant the whole time.

[image: resource monitor - memory]

I call [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) periodically and it has no effect. Although it seems to be a harmless case, I am concerned about this issue in terms of performance, as another Java application will also be running in a nominal operation.

Therefore, I would like to ask if I should worry about this and if there is a way to avoid this issue towards achieving the best performance for a real-time data recording system.

Similar questions have been asked [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/36817/) and [here](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/fwrite-consuming-lot-of-memory-help.438986/) for linux operating systems and it has been said that the system can devote an amount of memory for caching the data, as long as there is enough memory available.

A part of the application is presented next. In short, the application controls a pair of cameras and each of them acquires frames and store them in properly aligned allocated buffers. There are i) a CameraInterface class, which creates two "producer" threads, ii) a Recorder class, which creates two "consumer" threads and iii) a SharedMemoryManager class that provides a producer with an available buffer for storing data and a consumer with the next buffer to be written to the file. The SharedMemoryManager holds two arrays of buffers (one for each pair of producer-consumer) and two respective arrays of flags that indicate the status of the buffer. It also holds two [std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) objects for quick accessing of the next buffers to be recorder. Parts of the Recorder and the SharedMemoryManager are shown next.

```
// somewhere in file "atcore.h"...
typedef unsigned char AT_U8;

// File: SharedMemoryManager.h
#ifndef __MEM_MANAGER__
#define __MEM_MANAGER__

#pragma once

#include "atcore.h"
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>

#define NBUFFERS 128

#define BUFFER_AVAILABLE 0
#define BUFFER_QUEUED 1
#define BUFFER_FULL 2
#define BUFFER_RECORDING_PENDING 3

// the status flag cycle is
// EMPTY -> QUEUED -> FULL -> RECORDING_PENDING -> EMPTY

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    AT_U8** buffers;
    int* flags;
    int acquiredCounter;
    int consumedCounter;
    int queuedCounter;
    mutex flagMtx;
} sharedMemory;

typedef struct{
    AT_U8* buffer;
    int bufSize;
    int index;
} record;

class SharedMemoryManager
{
public:
    SharedMemoryManager();
    ~SharedMemoryManager(void);

    void enableRecording();
    void disableRecording();
    int setupMemory(int cameraIdentifier, int bufferSize);
    void freeMemory();
    void freeCameraMemory(int cameraIdentifier); 
    int getBufferSize(int cameraIdentifier);
    AT_U8* getBufferForCameraQueue(int cameraIdentifier);  // get pointer to the     next available buffer for queueing in the camera
    int hasFramesForRecording(int cameraIdentifier);  // ask how many frames for     recording are there in the respective queue
    AT_U8* getNextFrameForRecording(int cameraIdentifier);  // get pointer to the     next buffer to be recorded to a file
    void copyMostRecentFrame(unsigned char* buffer, int cameraIdentifier); //     TODO  // get a copy of the most recent frame on the buffer
    void notifyAcquiredFrame(AT_U8* buffer, int bufSize, int cameraIdentifier);      // use this function to notify the manager that the buffer has just been filled with     data
    void notifyRecordedFrame(AT_U8* buffer, int cameraIdentifier);  // use this function to notify the manager that the buffer has just been written to file and can be used again

private:
    bool useMem0, useMem1;
    int bufSize0, bufSize1;
    sharedMemory* memory0;
    sharedMemory* memory1;
    queue<record*> framesForRecording0;
    queue<record*> framesForRecording1;
    bool isRecording;

    int allocateBuffers(sharedMemory* mem, int bufSize);
    void freeBufferArray(sharedMemory* mem);
};

#endif  // !__MEM_MANAGER


// File: SharedMemoryManager.cpp
...
int SharedMemoryManager::hasFramesForRecording(int cameraIdentifier){
    if (cameraIdentifier!=0 && cameraIdentifier!=1){
        cout << "Could not get the number of frames in the shared memory. Invalid camera id " << cameraIdentifier << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (cameraIdentifier==0){
        return (int)framesForRecording0.size();
    }
    else{
        return (int)framesForRecording1.size();
    }
}

AT_U8* SharedMemoryManager::getNextFrameForRecording(int cameraIdentifier){
    if (cameraIdentifier!=0 && cameraIdentifier!=1){
        cout << "Error in getNextFrameForRecording. Invalid camera id " <<     cameraIdentifier << endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    sharedMemory* mem;
    if (cameraIdentifier==0) mem=memory0;
    else mem=memory1;

    queue<record*>* framesQueuePtr;
    if (cameraIdentifier==0) framesQueuePtr = &framesForRecording0;
    else framesQueuePtr = &framesForRecording1;

    if (framesQueuePtr->empty()){  // no frames to be recorded at the moment
        return NULL;
    }

    record* item;
    int idx;
    AT_U8* buffer = NULL;

    item = framesQueuePtr->front();
    framesQueuePtr->pop();
    idx = item->index;
    delete item;
    mem->flagMtx.lock();
    if (mem->flags[idx] == BUFFER_FULL){
        mem->flags[idx] = BUFFER_RECORDING_PENDING;
        buffer = mem->buffers[idx];
    }
    else{
        cout << "PROBLEM. Buffer in getBufferForRecording. Buffer flag is " <<     mem->flags[idx] << endl;
        cout << "----- BUFFER FLAGS -----" << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<NBUFFERS; i++){
            cout << "[" << i << "] " << mem->flags[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "----- -----" << endl;
    }
    mem->flagMtx.unlock();
    return buffer;
}

int SharedMemoryManager::allocateBuffers(sharedMemory* mem, int bufSize){
    // allocate the array for the buffers
    mem->buffers = (AT_U8**)calloc(NBUFFERS,sizeof(AT_U8*));
    if (mem->buffers==NULL){
        cout << "Could not allocate array of buffers." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // allocate the array for the respective flags
    mem->flags = (int*)malloc(NBUFFERS*sizeof(int));
    if (mem->flags==NULL){
        cout << "Could not allocate array of flags for the buffers." << endl;
        free(mem->buffers);
        return -1;
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NBUFFERS; i++){ // allocate the buffers
        mem->buffers[i] = (AT_U8*)_aligned_malloc((size_t)bufSize,8);
        if (mem->buffers[i] == NULL){
            cout << "Could not allocate memory for buffer no. " << i << endl;
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++){  // free the previously allocated buffers
                _aligned_free(mem->buffers[j]);
            }
            free(mem->buffers);
            free(mem->flags);
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            mem->flags[i]=BUFFER_AVAILABLE;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void SharedMemoryManager::freeBufferArray(sharedMemory* mem){
    if (mem!=NULL){
        for(int i=0; i<NBUFFERS; i++){
            _aligned_free(mem->buffers[i]);
            mem->buffers[i]=NULL;
        }
        free(mem->buffers);
        mem->buffers = NULL;
        free(mem->flags);
        mem->flags = NULL;
        free(mem);
        mem = NULL;
    }
}

// File: Recorder.h
#ifndef __RECORDER__
#define __RECORDER__

#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include "atcore.h"
#include "SharedMemoryManager.h"

using namespace std;

class Recorder
{
public:
    Recorder(SharedMemoryManager* memoryManager);
    ~Recorder();

    void recordBuffer(AT_U8 *buffer, int bufsize);
    int setupRecording(string filename0, string filename1, bool open0, bool open1);
    void startRecording();
    void stopRecording();
    int testWriteSpeed(string directoryPath, string filename);
    void insertFrameItem(AT_U8* buffer, int bufSize, int chunkID);

private:
    FILE *chunk0, *chunk1;
    string chunkFilename0, chunkFilename1;
    int frameCounter0, frameCounter1;
    bool writes0, writes1;
    int bufSize0, bufSize1;

    static SharedMemoryManager* manager;

    bool isRecording;

    promise<int> prom0;
    promise<int> prom1;
    thread* recordingThread0;
    thread* recordingThread1;

    static void performRecording(promise<int>* exitCode, int chunkIdentifier);
    void writeNextItem(int chunkIdentifier);
    void closeFiles();

};

#endif //!__RECORDER__

// File: Recorder.cpp
#include "Recorder.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Recorder* recorderInstance; // keep a pointer to the current instance, for accessing static functions from (non-static) objects in the threads
SharedMemoryManager* Recorder::manager;  // the same reason
...    
void Recorder::startRecording(){
    if (isRecording == false){  // do not start new threads if some are still running
        isRecording = true;
        if (writes0==true)  recordingThread0 = new thread(&Recorder::performRecording, &prom0, 0);
        if (writes1==true)  recordingThread1 = new thread(&Recorder::performRecording, &prom1, 1);
    }
}

void Recorder::writeNextItem(int chunkIdentifier){
    FILE* chunk;
    AT_U8* buffer;
    int* bufSize;
    if (chunkIdentifier==0){
        chunk = chunk0;
        bufSize = &bufSize0;
        buffer = manager->getNextFrameForRecording(0);
    }
    else {
        chunk = chunk1;
        bufSize = &bufSize1;
        buffer = manager->getNextFrameForRecording(1);
    }

    size_t nbytes = fwrite(buffer, 1, (*bufSize)*sizeof(unsigned char), chunk);
    if (nbytes<=0){
        cout << "No data were written to file." << endl;
    }

    manager->notifyRecordedFrame(buffer,chunkIdentifier);

    if (chunkIdentifier==0) frameCounter0++;
    else frameCounter1++;
}

void Recorder::performRecording(promise<int>* exitCode, int chunkIdentifier){
    bool flag = true;
    int remaining = manager->hasFramesForRecording(chunkIdentifier);
    while( recorderInstance->isRecording==true || remaining>0 ){
        if (remaining>0){
            if (recorderInstance->isRecording==false){
                cout << "Acquisition stopped, still " << remaining << " frames are to be recorded in chunk " << chunkIdentifier << endl;
            }
            recorderInstance->writeNextItem(chunkIdentifier);
        }
        else{
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
        remaining = manager->hasFramesForRecording(chunkIdentifier);
    }    
    cout << "Done recording." << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's more likely there's a memory leak in your code.

Comment: We get to see everything except the most important thing in this discussion -- your program.

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvious.

Comment: I will check for memory leaks; however, I have observed that this "modified" memory is still used even when I terminate the application (in contrast to the memory allocated for the buffers which is freed normally) and it starts decreasing in a slow rate, but it gets immediately freed when I delete the files that have been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Windows memory use screen shot you show, the biggest chunk (45GB) is "cached" of which 27GB is "modified", meaning "dirty pages waiting to be written to disk".  This is normal behavior because you are writing faster than the disk I/O can keep up.  flush/fflush has no effect on this because it is not in your process.  As you note: "the memory used by my application remains constant the whole time".  Do not be concerned.  However, if you *really* don't want the OS to buffer dirty output pages, consider using "unbuffered I/O" available on Windows, as it will write through immediately to disk.

Edit: Some links to unbuffered I/O on Windows.  Note that unbuffered I/O places memory-alignment constraints on your reads and writes.

[File Buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

[CreateFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Note that these pages do not show in the "available" total, because the OS cannnot simply discard them without first flushing them.